# Are there other factors, besides device and app vendor, that determine the identifierForVendor?

Tags: ios, ios6, uuid, uniqueidentifier

I noticed the identifierForVendor of my device changing for the app I am developing. I am pretty confident I didn't update the certificate for a while, so I wonder if there are other factors like app version etc...

Answer (score 2):

> Note that the OS automatically deletes the current identifierForVendor when the user deletes the last application from a particular vendor. If he later reinstalls one or more apps from that vendor, the OS will generate a new identifier. The identifierForVendor gets backed up during normal device backups. Restoring a backup to the same device will also restore all existing vendor identifiers. Because the identifier is device-specific, it will not be restored to a different device, though.

From http://oleb.net/blog/2012/09/udid-apis-in-ios-6/